# Zend Framework 3 tutorial error Album servicemanager

Tags: zend-framework3

An error occurred during execution; please try again later.

**Additional information:**

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't configure `Database Adapter`.  Here example. Put this code in

'path to project'

> 'path to project'/config/autoload/global.php

```
<?php


use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory;

return [
    'db' => [
        'adapters' => [
            'dbAdapter' => [
                'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
                'dsn' => "pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=DBNAME",
                'username' => 'USERNAME',
                'password' => 'PASSWORD',
        'driver_options' => [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
        ],
            ]
        ],    
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
        ],
        'abstract_factories' => [
   Zend\Navigation\Service\NavigationAbstractServiceFactory::class,
            AdapterAbstractServiceFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

`Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface` service is registered by the `zend-db` component. So make sure it is registered in `config/modules.config.php` (where resides `autoload` folder, `application.config.php` etc). Keep it mind this config file is not your (album) module's config file. So open up `config/modules.config.php`

```
return [
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',    // Make sure it exists
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    /* ... */
],
```

If this `Zend\Db` does not exist there then run the following command on your terminal

```
composer require zendframework/zend-db
```

If you get any prompt like the following

```
  Please select which config file you wish to inject 'Zend\Db' into:

  [0] Do not inject
  [1] config/modules.config.php
  Make your selection (default is 0):
```

Use `1` to get it registered into the `config/modules.config.php` in this case.

```
Remember this option for other packages of the same type? (y/N)
```

If you get another prompt like the above then simply put `y` to get rid of prompts further in zf component installation like this one.